# the input field is not resetting its content in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to reset the input. function works fine. I am reusing this template hence I have passed input and the list variable.

**Template**

```
<input 
    id="userlist" 
    [(ngModel)]="userInput" 
    class="form-input" type="text 
    (keyup.enter)="addInput(userInput,userList)"
/>
```

**component.ts**

```
userList: Array<string> = ['john', 'jane']
addInput(input, list) {
        if (input && input.length){
        list.push(input);
        input = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason why this is happening is that primitives, like a `string`, are always passed by value and not by reference. So `userList` is passed by reference and changes will have effect, but `input?  is passed by value, so changes won't have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `this.userInput=""` instead of `input`

Comment: but I am passing different inputs at different places, for example here I am passing userInput somewhere I am passing firstNameInput, emailInput, lastnameInput etc. hence to reduce the code I am passing each of these inputs as Input to the addInput method.

Comment: Please share full example in that case, because according to this piece of code this will work great but if you have more requirements please add full example

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned as comment:

The reason why this is happening is that primitives, like a string, are always passed by value and not by reference. So `userList` is passed by reference and changes will have effect, but `input` is passed by value, so changes won't have an effect.

As workaround, you could hold the data within an object to ensure it's passed by reference. I created a stackblitz solution for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y6ykgt

I added a class `ListInputData`, which holds both the list, the input and the `addInput` method now:

```
export class ListInputData {
  public list: string[] = [];
  public input: string = "";

  public constructor(list: string[], input?: string) { 
    this.list = list;
  }

  public addInput() {
    if (this.input && this.input.length) {
      this.list.push(this.input);
      this.input = "";
    }
  }  
}
```

And created a corresponding variable holding both the list and the input:

```
public userData: ListInputData = new ListInputData(["john", "jane"]);
```

And the usage within the component:

```
<input
    id="user-list"
    [(ngModel)]="userData.input"
    class="form-input" type="text"
    (keyup.enter)="userData.addInput()"
/>
```